# Is it possible to add dependencies in a pom.xml file?

Tags: maven, dependencies, settings, profile

My question may seem very simple but I did not know how to write it correctly ...

Here is my problem : I am testing an application using Cucumber and other libraries.
To do that, I had to add different dependencies to the pom.xml file of the Maven project I am testing.

In order to use all the work I made for further projects, I am now trying to create a settings.xml file in order to configure all others Maven projects with this document (avoiding copy/paste for all the pom.xml files). The fact is I manage to create profiles (which eases a little the work) but I can't find a way to automatically include all the dependencies I need.

Is there an easy way to do that ?

I hope my question is clear,
Thank you

Comment: settings.xml for other projects is simply wrong. dependencies which are only for tests can be defined with scope test...

Comment: Dependencies with profiles is also bad...If you need having different dependencies for Testings make better separate module which contain the appropriate dependencies. Separation of concerns...

Answer (score 1):

You can't add dependencies from settings.xml profiles.
You need to add them in projects pom.xml files (or in the parent of those).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers !! I think I will have no other solution than copy/paste each time all my dependencies then...

Regards